# How to release GPU memory in tensorflow? (opposite of `allow_growth` → `allow_shrink`?)

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, gpu-managed-memory

I'm using a GPU to train quite a lot of models. I want to tune the architecture of the network, so I train different models sequentially to compare their performances (I'm using `keras-tuner`).

The problem is that some models are very small, and some others are very large. I don't want to allocate all the GPU memory to my trainings, but only the quantity I need. I've `TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH` to `true`, meaning that when a model requires a large quantity of memory, then the GPU will allocate it. However, once that big model has been trained, the memory will not be released, even if the next trainings are tiny models.

Is there a way to force the GPU to release unused memory? Something like `TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_SHRINK`?

Maybe having an automatic shrinking might be difficult to achieve. If so I would be happy with a manual releasing that I could add in a callback to be run after each training.